# Openpgp Encrypt with PGP

Tags: node.js, openpgp.js

I am trying to encrypt a message using PGP but I am getting an error that states:

```
ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined

      at Object.decodeUTF8 (node_modules/openpgp/src/util.js:225:21)
      at Do.read (node_modules/openpgp/src/packet/userid.js:78:25)
      at callback (node_modules/openpgp/src/packet/packetlist.js:82:28)
      at Xs (node_modules/openpgp/src/packet/packet.js:282:13)
      at node_modules/openpgp/src/packet/packetlist.js:96:11
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
    const plainData = random.uuid()
    const publicKeyArmored = fs.readFileSync('/path/any.asc').toString();
    const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey( { armoredKey: publicKeyArmored } )
    console.log(publicKey)
```

When I print the `publicKeyArmored`, all is OK. As soon as it reaches the `console.log` shown before, the error appears

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up making this work, I hope it helps someone:

```
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp'

  const plainText = 'Any text you wanna encrypt'
  const textEncoding = await import('text-encoding-utf-8')
  global.TextEncoder = textEncoding.TextEncoder
  global.TextDecoder = textEncoding.TextDecoder

  const publicKeyArmored = fs.readFileSync('/path/any.asc').toString();

  const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyArmored })
  const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
    message: openpgp.Message.fromText(plainText),
    publicKeys: [publicKey]
  })
  console.log(encrypted)
```

Comment: similar issue we faced and able to fixed it